# defbeforePeriod(s):

Tags: python, string, helper

How do I write a Python function beginning with defbeforePeriod(s): that returns the substring that precedes the first period in the string s, the parameter.  The string contains a period.  So if s is "abc2.3ty", my function would return "abc2"

Comment: ... Have you worked through the tutorial yet?

Comment: I just can't figure this out

Comment: Try looking at the `split` method of strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def beforePeriod(s):
    m = re.match('(.*)\..*',s)
    if m:
       return m.groups()[0]
```

or

```
def beforePeriod(s):
   return s[s:s.index('.')]
```

or

```
   def beforePeriod(s):
       return s.split('.')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look through the docs.python.org section [5.6.1. String Methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) you will see a `str.find()` function:

> str.find(sub[, start[, end]])
>      Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found ... The find() method should be used only if you need to know the position of sub.

`find()` can be used as shown in the following example, which is snipped from an ipython interpreter transcript.

```
In [2]: def defbeforePeriod(s):
   ...:     return s[:s.find('.')]
   ...: 

In [3]: defbeforePeriod('abc2.3ty')
Out[3]: 'abc2'

In [4]: defbeforePeriod('abc2.3ty.zeta')
Out[4]: 'abc2'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to manipulate filenames, have a look at [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html), in particular [`os.path.splitext()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext).

Comment: I downvoted because this user definitely needs to focus on the standard library before venturing into `import` statements.

Comment: The larger part of the standard library (with the exception of the built-in constants, types and functions) _has_ to be imported. And it is a very important part of python to learn.

Comment: Eh, [you're right](http://docs.python.org/2/library/), the standard library is more than just the [built in functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html). That's what I meant.

Comment: I think it is important to learn start learning _all_ of the standard library, so you don't end up reinventing parts of it!